# How to get self-adjoint extension?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, laplacian

**Motivation:** I am trying to understand the proof of [Section 1.1 here p.4-5](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02716.pdf).  I am trying to see the operator  $-\Delta + \frac{a}{|x|^2}$ is  positive semi-definite
symmetric operator.  (And so will have  [Friedrichs extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrichs_extension))

Let $\mathcal{L}_a^0$ denote the natural action of $- \Delta + \frac{a}{|x|^2}$
on  $C_c^{\infty} (\mathbb R^{N}\setminus \{0\})$ ($a\geq - \left(\frac{N-2}{2} \right) ^{2}$).

**Questions:**

(1)How to show
$$ \mathcal{L}_a^0 = \left( - \nabla + \sigma \frac{x}{|x|^2} \right) \cdot \left( \nabla + \sigma \frac{x}{|x|^2} \right)= - \Delta - \sigma (N-2 - \sigma) \frac{1}{|x|^2},$$
with  $\sigma= \frac{N-2}{2}- \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(N-2)^2 + 4a}$\
(2) How to use (1) to conculde that 
that for  $\phi \in C_c^{\infty} (\mathbb R^N \setminus\{0\})$  we have
 $$ \langle \phi, \mathcal{L}_a^0 \phi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla \phi(x) + \sigma \frac{x}{|x|^2} \phi(x)|^2 dx \geq 0 ?$$

**My Rough Attempt:**  Let $N=3.$ (1)  Note that\ $  \left( - \nabla + \sigma \frac{x}{|x|^2} \right) \cdot \left( \nabla + \sigma \frac{x}{|x|^2} \right)= \left( -\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\sigma \frac{x_1}{|x|^2} , ..., -\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}+\sigma \frac{x_1}{|x|^2} \right) \cdot  \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\sigma \frac{x_1}{|x|^2} , ..., \frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}+\sigma \frac{x_1}{|x|^2} \right) = -\Delta + \sigma^2 \frac{1}{|x|^2
 }$

I am wondering, in the aboe identity why one could get: $\mathcal{L}_a^0= -\Delta - \sigma (3-2-\sigma) \frac{1}{|x|^2} = - \Delta +(\sigma^2 - \sigma) \frac{1}{|x|^2}$

I have noticed that: $-\sigma + \sigma^2 =a$

(2) In proving, second how should I interprest inner product: should I take $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_{\mathbb R^3} f(x) \overline{g(x)} dx$ Or $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_{\mathbb R^3} \nabla f(x) \cdot \overline{\nabla g(x)} dx ?$

Is it true that: $|\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla (-\Delta - \sigma(N-2-\sigma)\frac{1}{|x|^2})\phi(x)|= |\nabla \phi(x) + \sigma \frac{x}{|x|^2} \phi(x)|$? (How should I proceed...)